# SPServices not retrieving populated Lookup Fields

Tags: spservices, sharepoint-list

I have been searching the Internet for a solution, but from what I can tell, I am doing everything correctly. I have a List that has a lot of Lookup Fields. I specify all of the fields I want to come back but the only ones that don't are the Lookup Fields even though I know some of them have values. Is there something else I'm missing?

If it matters, my SPServices version is 0.7.2 and I'm on SharePoint 2010.

```
var query = "<Query> \
    <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ItemID + "</Value></Eq></Where> \
</Query>";

var listFields = "<ViewFields> \
    <FieldRef Name='Version' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Function ID' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Function Name' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Function Description' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='GovernanceDescription' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Governance Documentation' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Compliance Register Items' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Execute BU 10' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='ExecuteDescription10' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Oversight BU 10' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='OversightDescription10' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support_BU_1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='Support BU 10' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription1' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription2' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription3' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription4' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription5' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription6' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription7' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription8' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription9' /> \
    <FieldRef Name='SupportDescription10' /> \
</ViewFields>";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "GOES Functions",
    CAMLQuery: query,
    CAMLViewFields: listFields,
    completefunc: function (data, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
            var json = XMLItemToJSON($(data.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row")[0]);

        } else if (status == "error") {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get all your fields back if you use this: `CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />"`

Comment: It looks like you're not using the internal names. For example, the internal name for `Execute BU 10` is probably `Execute_x0020_BU_x002010` 

Do you know how to get internal names?

Comment: Oh. Uggh. I feel stupid now. Lol. I will try that tomorrow. I think that will be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the internal name: `Execute_x0020_BU_x002010` instead of `Execute BU 10`

Answer (score 0):

After doing the suggestion by Erin L above, I was able to get my code working. I should have been totally aware of this, but it slipped my mind.

Be sure your field names are "encoded" properly and not the display value for that field.